# How to upgrade from Java EE to Jakarta with webdav-servlet compatibility?

Tags: java

I am facing issues while upgrading from Java EE to Jakarta, specifically with the webdav-servlet. It appears that the current version of webdav-servlet does not support Jakarta. Currently, I am using OpenJdk 11.

The problem arises in the servlet-class section of the web.xml file:

```xml
<servlet>
...
        <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            net.sf.webdav.WebdavServlet
        </servlet-class>
..
</servlet>
```

Any suggestions or workarounds on how to resolve this compatibility issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “ this compatibility issue” — *what* compatibility issue? You have not explained exactly what problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to detail the nature of your specific problem. I am guessing your problem is either or both of these issues:

- The current version of [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/) requires the use of `jakarta.*` package naming, a break from the past use of `javax.*` namespace.
- The current version of the [Jakarta Servlet](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.servlet) spec drops some deprecated features.

In any case, your Servlet appears to be [this project](https://github.com/ceefour/webdav-servlet). Unfortunately, that project seems to show no activity in over nine years. So I assume that rules out any possibility of an update.

If you want to move to modern Jakarta technology, replace that Servlet with another providing your needed functionality.

If you need help in selecting an implementation of a [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) server, post on the sister site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/